# How do I turn this search function to show only records that belong to that particular user?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I was able to filter out the displayed data on first load for a particular user by searching a column by using Tanaike's method [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75066197/how-do-i-only-search-for-a-specific-column-but-still-show-the-whole-row-as-array). The search functions works fine but the thing is, the user can also search for other people's record in the google sheet as long as they search for a value existing in the spreadsheet. I am thinking of a way to add a second && condition to show only the rows that only matches that currentUser's username (in column C) and the searched value.

```
function displayOwnRecordSearch(currentUser, searchedValue){

var spreadsheetId   = "";
var sheetName = "";  
var column = 3;

var [, ...data] = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, sheetName).values;
var arr = [];


  if(searchedValue !== undefined) {
      const validateText = (query) => {
      let regex = new RegExp(searchedValue, 'i')
         return regex.test(query)
   }
  data.forEach(d => {
    if (validateText(d)) {
      arr.push(d);
     }
  });
  
  }else{
     const validateText = (query) => {
     let regex = new RegExp(currentUser, 'i')
         return regex.test(query)
   }
  data.forEach(d => {
    if (validateText(d[column - 1])) {
      arr.push(d);
     }
  });
 }

 return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about using `fiter` as follows?

#### Modified script:

```js
function displayOwnRecordSearch(currentUser, searchedValue) {
  var spreadsheetId = "###";
  var sheetName = "###";
  var columnForCurrentUser = 3; // Column "C".
  var columnForSearchedValue = 5; // Column "E". This is from https://stackoverflow.com/q/75066197 (your previous question)

  var [, ...data] = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, sheetName).values;
  var arr = data.filter(r => (new RegExp(currentUser, 'i')).test(r[columnForCurrentUser - 1]) && (new RegExp(searchedValue, 'i')).test(r[columnForSearchedValue - 1]));
  // console.log(arr); // You can check the value in the log.
  return arr;
}
```

- In this modification, From [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75066197), I used `var columnForSearchedValue = 5;` as the column for `searchedValue`.
- Or, I think that `var [, ...data] = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, sheetName).values;` can be also modified as follows.

  ```js
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  ```

#### Reference:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: I tried it but somehow it still shows the data from other users. Is there an approach instead using the if(searchedValue !== undefined && other code here...)

Comment: @codeTester- Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `I tried it but somehow it still shows the data from other users. Is there an approach instead using the if(searchedValue !== undefined && other code here...)`, in this case, it is required to know your situation. So, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Here is the sample data [sheet](https://imgur.com/a/EC0XX2H)

What I have now is a datatable that loads the data using the currentUser's username by Session.getActiveUser().getUsername(); basing on column E

It is working to fetch the correct data only belonging to the current logged in user. But when I use the search function, I can search for other's data as long as my search matches any data in any row., which is what I do not want to happen. 

What I am wanting to accomplish is to show only data/row that belongs to currentUser matching column E when searching.

Comment: @codeTester- Thank you for replying. About `What I have now is a datatable that loads the data using the currentUser's username by Session.getActiveUser().getUsername(); basing on column E It is working to fetch the correct data only belonging to the current logged in user.`, I couldn't notice about it from your question. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About your new situation, in your situation, how is the script run?

Comment: No need to be sorry my friend. Currently the script runs to show only data that belong to the logged in user in column E. For example, when person.two opens the app he can only see rowId 2. But when he uses the search function, he can search for the word "Laptop" and rowId 1 will show, even though that data belongs to person.one

Comment: @codeTester- Thank you for replying. In order to retrieve the user's information using `Session.getActiveUser().getUsername();`, it is required to know the method for executing the script. So, I asked it. But, from your reply, I cannot know it. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: @codeTester- Although, unfortunately, I cannot know your current script including `I have now is a datatable that loads the data using the currentUser's username by Session.getActiveUser().getUsername(); basing on column E It is working to fetch the correct data only belonging to the current logged in user.`, if the values of `currentUser, searchedValue` are set and those values are included in the Spreadsheet, the values can be filtered by my proposed script. So, please don't worry.

Comment: @codeTester- I'm worried that your current issue is different from your initial question. In order to test my proposed script, can you test my proposed script using the sample values of `currentUser, searchedValue` you manually set?